# Aggregating rows in file by minute

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to aggregate data from a CSV file by minute.

The expected output is the number of sessions (3rd column) in one minute

**Input:**

```
30/Jan/2018, 04:01:04, tRhmNvNQG2Ykjz5UrQopDwe
30/Jan/2018, 04:01:09, BKB4UlW2je-fM4vNi5dkO9E
30/Jan/2018, 04:01:19, fjD7lGCc48BBRkPsPNv_iOt
30/Jan/2018, 04:01:32, eqdgbdf54tBBRkPsPNv_iOt
30/Jan/2018, 04:01:46, GhylG7J21i5t-974mGlElWO
30/Jan/2018, 04:01:51, GhylG7J21i5t-974mGlElWO
30/Jan/2018, 04:02:07, GhylG7J21i5t-974mGlElWO
30/Jan/2018, 04:02:17, WnjtqtPr6dqjHoG2YbOD1js
30/Jan/2018, 04:02:28, elz45MJQoPnAJUTQS8Lwkd8
30/Jan/2018, 04:02:38, TUJbbsUZd0txgADVd7PsJrd
30/Jan/2018, 04:02:48, WnjtqtPr6dqjHoG2YbOD1js
```

**Expected Output:**

```
30/Jan/2018, 04:01, 6
30/Jan/2018, 04:02, 5
```

Comment: please add what you've tried to question - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **awk**

```
$ awk -F":" '{a[$1 FS $2]++; next} END{for(i in a) print i", "a[i]}' file
30/Jan/2018, 04:01, 6
30/Jan/2018, 04:02, 5
```

`-F":"` field delimiter is `:`

`a[$1 FS $2]++;` to create associative arrays with combined fields `1` and `2` as keys and the value as counts

`END{for(i in a) print i", "a[i]}` : to print the desired result

**Note:** This won't guarantee a sorted result. In case you want a sorted result based on descending order on count then you can pipe the result to `sort`

```
$ awk -F":" '{a[$1 FS $2]++; next} END{for(i in a) print i", "a[i]}' file | sort -t, -nrk3
30/Jan/2018, 04:01, 6
30/Jan/2018, 04:02, 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. The file is already sorted by time. Your solution works best for large (~512MB)  files.

Comment: @SaurabhMishra: It doesn't matter if the file is sorted. Awk array traversal orders are not defined and completely depends on internal implementation. I therefore, recommend to sort the output explicitly using sort.  In GNU awk it can be done internally using `PROCINFO` but I don't recommend it as it varies highly with the awk version.  The other way we can do it internally is by keeping second array of keys and using it to traverse the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your Input_file is same as shown sample then following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F'[/, :]' '{a[$1"/"$2"/"$3", "$5":"$6]++} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: `awk` is definitely the shorter way to go `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple little bash script that takes the log filename to read and outputs the summarized session count. Essentially the script just loops over the entries keeping a count, parses the minute, compares it to the last minute and if they differ, outputs the last date/hour:min and count:

```
#!/bin/bash

fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"   ## read from file "$1" or stdin

[ -r "$fn" ] || {       ## validate file readable
    printf "error: unable to read from filename or stdin\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

lastdt=     ## declare last date, hour, min, count
lasthr=
lastmn=
declare -i cnt=0

while IFS+=',' read -r dt tm s; do          ## read each csv
    hr="${tm:0:2}"                          ## get hour and minute
    min="${tm:3:2}"
    if [ -n "$lastdt" ]; then               ## do we have a lastdt?
        if [ "$min" != "$lastmn" ]; then    ## if lastmin not current
            printf "%s, %s:%s, %d\n" "$lastdt" "$lasthr" "$lastmn" $cnt
            cnt=0   ## reset count
        fi
    fi

    lastdt="$dt"    ## save last values
    lasthr="$hr"
    lastmn="$min"
    ((cnt++))       ## increment count

done < "$fn"

## output final session count
printf "%s, %s:%s, %d\n" "$lastdt" "$lasthr" "$lastmn" $cnt
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash logsessions.sh log.csv
30/Jan/2018, 04:01, 6
30/Jan/2018, 04:02, 5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.